# Vim. How to remap default navigation ('w', 'b', 'e'...) keys

Tags: vim

Is there a way to change 'w' key behavior to make it actually behave like 'b' key? Failed to find navigation commands if there is any.

UPDATE

In Vim key 'w' in normal mode is used to navigate to first letter of the next word. 'e' key is used to navigate to last letter of the next word. It would be great to use 'w' key to navigate to PREVIOUS word (like 'b' key behave) instead of the next one. When jumping from one word to another with 'e' you miss desired word (which happens very frequently) and you need to jump one word back, it is absolutely annoying to take off you hand and search for 'b' key instead of 'w' key which is currently right under your finger, and is unused by me at all.

It sometimes frustrating to have such customizable tool like Vim and not being able to simply remap default navigation keys. It is possible in almost all relatively modern IDEs or even text editors.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for? Help doc on [`w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#w)

Comment: @Shadoath Is this update counts as an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [remap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping#3776182) in your vimrc file. For example I have:

```
nnoremap 0 ^
vnoremap 0 ^
```

Which makes `0` respond as if I hit `^` taking me to the first non-whitespace character on the current line.  These remaps ONLY effect Normal and Visual mode due to the preceding 'n' and 'v' In your case to map `w` to `b` in Normal mode:

```
nnoremap w b
```

I would **HIGHLY** recommend you **DON'T** do this. There are a ton of different ways to navigate and overwriting a command like `w` will cause issues down the road because now all Normal mode commands will be `b` instead of `w`.

My opinion is that your vim skill would improve if you set out to learn all the other ways to navigate. Such as: `W` or `B` to jump a full [WORD](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD). Or `f` and `t` to jump to the next letter typed (inclusive/exclusive respectively & capital `F` and `T` take you backward). You can precede any of these with a number to repeat that command. So `3w` jumps 3 words forward.

Docs on [motion](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#m) operators and [map-modes](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-modes).

Comment: Works! Thank you! I'll keep in mind you recommendation though.